# C# API with lots of optional parameters demands values in all of them

Tags: c#

I suspect this is going to be an easy fix, but... Here's the (labourious) API for a method...

```
public void Add(int StyleIn = 0, string DefaultValueIn = "",
  string ComboListValuesIn = "", string MinIn = "", string MaxIn = "",
  int MaxLengthIn = -1, bool HighlightIn = false,
  string StartDateIn = "", string EndDateIn = "", string MethodIn = "",
  string AccountIn = "", string AmountTypeIn = "", bool PositiveIn = true,
  int ResultTypeIn = -1, DtaColumn DtaColIn = null)
```

All good? Well when I try to call it...

```
DC.Add(dbEditText, "Property", , , , , , , , , , , , , DC);
```

It tells me that every one of those empty parameters is missing. I counted carefully and they're all there. If I replace the empty ones with "" then it starts working... so it's like it's ignoring the optionals?

This code was converted from VS if you're wondering.

Comment: explicitly set each one to null?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case you need to make the last parameter named:

```
DC.Add(dbEditText, "Property", DtaColIn: DC);
```

Comment: This looks like the perfect solution. Should I name all of them if there are any blanks in the middle, or only the last one?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz It doesn't matter. But I would prefer naming them all, it's a bad practice to mix named and unnamed arguments.

Answer (score 3):

That is an extraordinarily ugly API!  You can't pass blank values in C#, which is why your attempt to use empty strings and commas failed in your question.  You have two ways to solve this.

1. Pass `null` for each "blank" value
2. Use [Named Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

Whenever you have optional parameters you can either pass a value, or pass null.  The only time you can leave them blank is if all the following parameters will use the default values.

This is allowed:

```
DC.Add(dbEditText, "property");
DC.Add(dbEditText, "property", null, null, null, null, null, "something");
```

This is not:

```
DC.Add(dbEditText,"property",,"something");
```

Notice how in the allowed example anything AFTER the parameter of "property" will use the default values.  However, in your case you want to set a value to some 'random' parameters.  This is when you use named parameters.  Using @EldarDordzhiev's example:

```
DC.Add(dbEditText, "property", DtaColIn: DC);
```

This allows you to first use ordered parameters (when the parameter name is not specified), but nothing can be skipped.  When you want to skip some you start using the named parameters.  This will allow for the specified value to be set for that particular parameter.  Any missing optional will then be set to the default values.

Comment: I am finding the differences between C# and VB rather surprising. This is one of those surprises - the API works fine in VB. C'est la vie! Naming them seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider refactoring the code a bit and introduce a command object - class that would encapsulate all parameters and then use that class as an parameter of the method:

```
public class ApiParameters{

    public int StyleIn {get; set;}
    public string {get; set;}
    public string {get; set;}
    public string {get; set;}
    public string {get; set;}

}
```

And then:
`DC.Add(ApiParameters params);`

As the solution proposed by Eldar is correct, this one makes the code a little bit easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

That's because if you are going to pass a value for any of the optional parameters, all optional parameters up to that one need some kind of value passed also.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx):

> Optional parameters are defined at the end of the parameter list, after any required parameters. If the caller provides an argument for any one of a succession of optional parameters, it must provide arguments for all preceding optional parameters. Comma-separated gaps in the argument list are not supported.

As @user1666620 mentioned, if you use the Name of the last parameter and pass that as a Named Argument, you can then just omit the comma-separated list of empty parameters in between.